# How iOS how to get exif, markernote data

Tags: ios, swift, image, exif

I use the iOS sound method to read these data, but I found that all these data are some regular data, and then the new data is correct such as retest-specific data I can't read, and I don't know where to get it from!

I try use image/io

```
static public func getImageInfo(url: URL) {
    if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL, nil) {
        if let MetadataProperties = CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as? [String: Any] {
            print("All Image Metadata: \(MetadataProperties)")
            print("All Image Metadata: \(MetadataProperties)")
        }
        
        
        let imageCount = CGImageSourceGetCount(imageSource)
        print("Image Count: \(imageCount)")
        
        for i in 0..<imageCount {
            if let properties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, i, nil) as? [CFString: Any] {
                print("Properties of image at index \(i): \(properties)")
            }
        }
        
        if let properties2 = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as? [CFString: Any],
           let makerNote = properties2[kCGImagePropertyMakerAppleDictionary] as? Any {
            print("Maker Note: \(makerNote)")
            print("Maker Note: \(makerNote)")
        }
    }
}
```

But I want some special data for iOS.  For example, the photo mode of the sony, Fujifilm camera. jpeg.

Because it seems iOS doesn't have it.  exiftool or exifv2

here is normal data.

```json
{
  "{Exif}" : {
    "ApertureValue" : 2.6000000000000001,
    "BodySerialNumber" : "3T102913",
    "BrightnessValue" : 0.050000000000000003,
    "ColorSpace" : 1,
    "ComponentsConfiguration" : [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      0
    ],
    "CompositeImage" : 1,
    "CompressedBitsPerPixel" : 4.7999999999999998,
    "CustomRendered" : 0,
    "DateTimeDigitized" : "2023:10:29 20:28:42",
    "DateTimeOriginal" : "2023:10:29 20:28:42",
    "ExifVersion" : [
      2,
      3,
      2
    ],
    "ExposureBiasValue" : -1,
    "ExposureMode" : 0,
    "ExposureProgram" : 2,
    "ExposureTime" : 0.0028571428571428571,
    "FileSource" : 3,
    "Flash" : 0,
    "FlashPixVersion" : [
      1,
      0
    ],
    "FNumber" : 2.5,
    "FocalLength" : 27,
    "FocalLenIn35mmFilm" : 41,
    "FocalPlaneResolutionUnit" : 3,
    "FocalPlaneXResolution" : 2660,
    "FocalPlaneYResolution" : 2660,
    "ISOSpeedRatings" : [
      5000
    ],
    "LensMake" : "VILTROX ",
    "LensModel" : "AF 27\/1.2 XF      ",
    "LensSerialNumber" : "00000000",
    "LensSpecification" : [
      27,
      27,
      1.2000000476837158,
      1.2000000476837158
    ],
    "LightSource" : 0,
    "MaxApertureValue" : 0.5,
    "MeteringMode" : 5,
    "OffsetTime" : "+08:00",
    "OffsetTimeDigitized" : "+08:00",
    "OffsetTimeOriginal" : "+08:00",
    "PixelXDimension" : 6240,
    "PixelYDimension" : 3512,
    "SceneCaptureType" : 0,
    "SceneType" : 1,
    "SensingMethod" : 2,
    "SensitivityType" : 1,
    "Sharpness" : 1,
    "ShutterSpeedValue" : 8.5099999999999998,
    "SubjectDistRange" : 0,
    "WhiteBalance" : 0
  },
  "{ExifAux}" : {
    "AFInfo" : [
      0.40544870495796204,
      0.59866172075271606,
      0.05000000074505806,
      0.049829158931970596,
      "f"
    ],
    "FocusMode" : 1,
    "LensInfo" : [
      27,
      27,
      1.2,
      1.2
    ],
    "LensModel" : "27.0 mm f\/1.2"
  },
  "{IPTC}" : {
    "Byline" : [
      "DG                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "
    ],
    "CopyrightNotice" : "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ",
    "StarRating" : 0
  },
  "{PictureStyle}" : {
    "Contrast" : [
      "Normal",
      0,
      0
    ],
    "FilmSimulation" : [
      "1536",
      1536,
      1536
    ],
    "Monochrome" : [
      "0",
      0,
      0
    ],
    "PictStyleColorSpace" : [
      "sRGB",
      1,
      1
    ],
    "PictureStyle" : [
      "Program AE",
      6,
      6
    ],
    "Saturation" : [
      "Medium Low",
      384,
      -1
    ],
    "Sharpness" : [
      "Soft2",
      2,
      -3
    ]
  },
  "{TIFF}" : {
    "Artist" : "DG                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ",
    "Copyright" : "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ",
    "DateTime" : "2023:10:29 20:28:42",
    "Make" : "FUJIFILM",
    "Model" : "X-S20",
    "Orientation" : 1,
    "ResolutionUnit" : 2,
    "Software" : "Digital Camera X-S20 Ver1.10",
    "XResolution" : 72,
    "YResolution" : 72
  },
  "ColorModel" : "RGB",
  "Depth" : 8,
  "DPIHeight" : 72,
  "DPIWidth" : 72,
  "Orientation" : 1,
  "PixelHeight" : 3512,
  "PixelWidth" : 6240,
  "ProfileName" : "sRGB IEC61966-2.1"
}
```

but i want some like Shaow, heightlight.

```
0x1001
Sharpness
0x0 = -4 (softest)
0x1 = -3 (very soft)
0x2 = -2 (soft)
0x3 = 0 (normal)
0x4 = +2 (hard)
0x5 = +3 (very hard)
0x6 = +4 (hardest)
0x82 = -1 (medium soft)
0x84 = +1 (medium hard)
0x8000 = Film Simulation
0xffff = n/a
WhiteBalance
0x0 = Auto
0x1 = Auto (white priority)
0x2 = Auto (ambiance priority)
0x100 = Daylight
0x200 = Cloudy
0x300 = Daylight Fluorescent
0x301 = Day White Fluorescent
0x302 = White Fluorescent
0x303 = Warm White Fluorescent
0x304 = Living Room Warm White Fluorescent
0x400 = Incandescent
0x500 = Flash
0x600 = Underwater
0xf00 = Custom
0xf01 = Custom2
0xf02 = Custom3
0xf03 = Custom4
0xf04 = Custom5
0xff0 = Kelvin
Saturation

0x0 = Normal
0x80 = Medium High
0x100 = High
0x180 = Medium Low
0x200 = Low
0x8000 = Film Simulation
NoiseReduction 
0x0 = 0 (normal)
0x100 = +2 (strong)
0x180 = +1 (medium strong)
0x1c0 = +3 (very strong)
0x1e0 = +4 (strongest)
0x200 = -2 (weak)
0x280 = -1 (medium weak)
0x2c0 = -3 (very weak)
0x2e0 = -4 (weakest)
```

I'll add that I'd like to have access to some of Fujifilm's special markernote data, such as these, which they don't provide in iOS, but I can figure them out in exiftool; I can't use exiftool on iOS, so is there any good way to do this?

Comment: It's not easy to understand this question but do you mean something like `kCGImagePropertyMakerFujiDictionary`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and be more clear which metadata properties you already get and which exactly you are trying to get.

Comment: ExifTool does make great efforts to output the metadata from different manufacturers in a standardized, human readable format. You may not get it so easy in iOS.

Comment: This may help to read single properties from the dictionary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34254148/16157878

Comment: what do you mean with "Shaow, heightlight"?

Comment: Shadow, Highlight. Custom properties that are specific for some camera makers and not part of the standard metadata properties is my guess.